# Windows software to convert GeoJSON (> 6Mb) to Excel/CSV?

Tags: geojson, convert, csv, software-recommendations, large-datasets

I am trying to convert OpenStreetmap data GeoJSON to Excel (or .csv files). Few online converters are there.

However, when the file is big (example: 6Mb Geojson), the browser is becoming unresponsive. So I am looking for converters that will handle big files. My current software, Opal converter, is unresponsive when converting big files.

Is there any windows desktop software available to convert GeoJSON greater than 6Mb to Excel/CSV?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).  In the words of the Tour: `Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.`  I'm quite sure there are many GIS and *non-GIS* packages capable of achieving your goal.  The exact details are dependent on what you mean by "Excel/CSV", since that encompasses thousands of potential formats.

Comment: Yes plenty of ways

Comment: I am actually trying to convert OpenStreetmap data GeoJson to Excel. Few online converters are there. But when the file is big (ex.6MB Geojson), browser is becoming unresponsive. So i am trying to good converters that will handle big files. I have one software Opal converter which is also unresponsive when converting big files!!

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any additional details like these.

Comment: @EF1897 did any of these solutions work for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using QGIS, load the GeoJSON as a standard vector layer.

Right click - save as - Format = Comma Separated Value (CSV)

If you want to take the geometry with you, you have under Layer Options:

GEOMETRY:

- as XY (best for point data)
- as WKT (will write out something you can more easily port back over to geometry later if using lines, polygons, etc)

Answer (score 3):

The usual answer to any vector reformatting question is ogr2ogr. It will work here too. Use OSGeo4w to install it on a windows box.

Answer (score 1):

http://geojson.io/ lets you upload a file and save it as a CSV (as well as TopoJson, KML, WKT and so on)