# GeoJSON to CSV with geometry using QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, csv, geometry-conversion

I downloaded a GeoJSON file from vangdata.carto.com and I'm trying to convert it to CSV that has geometry data in tact. I'm trying to achieve the same result as a CSV file when exported from public.opendatasoft.com which is following:

This is the `Geo_Shape` column

```
"{""type"": ""MultiPolygon"", ""coordinates"": [[[[3.20543629, 42.07333392606152], [3.206103403, 42.07336071406152], [3.20583872...
```

Which then is very easy to digest by BigQuery. Unfortunately, online converters seem to only export the textual data from GeoJSON, leaving the geometry out completely.

In QGIS, when I load GeoJSON file, the map shows correctly:
[image]

Then right click -> Export -> Save Feature As

[image]
[image]

The settings are standard, I leave Geometry section as Automatic but unfortunately the exported CSV does not contain the geometry column at all

I stumbled upon this topic that gave me the idea of using QGIS to convert those files rather than online converters:  [Windows software to convert GeoJSON (> 6Mb) to Excel/CSV?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174898/windows-software-to-convert-geojson-6mb-to-excel-csv)

How can I convert the GeoJSON (or TopoJSON or even Shapefile - I can get any from vangdata.carto.com) to a CSV with geometry column like above?

Comment: "that has in tact" is a typo, but I can't figure out what you meant to type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `Layer Options > GEOMETRY` to any option except `<Default>` in `Save Vector Layer as...` window.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and it worked with `GEOMETRY > AS_WKT`, all the others would remove the geometry column. And of course WKT is also compatible with BigQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [this official GDAL recipe](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html) if you prefer command line

```
ogr2ogr -f CSV -dialect sqlite -sql "select AsGeoJSON(geometry) AS geom, * from input" output.csv input.shp
```