# ArcGIS Export attribute table from imported GeoJSON to CSV w/Geometry

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv, well-known-text

I'm trying to use GeoJSON files to generate CSV that I can then upload to my data warehouse and use the geography fields to create a connection between the lat/lng in the database and the GeoJSON map files.

How do I export the attribute table as CSV but include geometry as WKT?

I used to do it in QGIS: [GeoJSON to CSV with geometry using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388341/geojson-to-csv-with-geometry-using-qgis) but I wanted to try to do it in ArcGIS Pro and can't figure it out.